# How to select all the days of the week from a given day?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Given a date I want to get all the other days of that same week, where in the week starts and ends on Saturday and Friday.

Model

```
public TimeModel
{
   public int ID
   public DateTime Day
}
```

What I'm currently doing

```
public Contrller{
private db = new ModelContext();

public AddDates(DateTime Date)
{
    List<Model> list = new List<Model>();      
    int n = 0;

   while(Date.DayofWeek != DayofWeek.Sauturday)
   Date = Date.AddDats(-1)  // keep subracting the date until I reach Saturday

   while(Date.DayofWeek != DayofWeek.Friday
  {
     list.Add(Find(Date)); 
    //Simply put for each date not Friday
    // I find the corresponding model (the one with the same date) 
    //and add it to the list 

     Date = Date.AddDays(1)
  }

   list.Add(Find(Date)); // To add the Friday date to list 


  }
```

Note: Not exactly my code, just a simplification of my problem.

To summarize my solution: 
a) Subtract given date until Saturday 
b) Find model which corresponds to Date 
c) Repeat until I reach Friday 
d) Add to list once more to include Friday

Is it possible to create a linq/sql statement to simpyly select the needed models (with regards to Date)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a sample implementation that gets the current week.

```
        List<TimeModel> list = new List<TimeModel>();
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            list.Add(new TimeModel{ID = i, Day = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i)});


        var currentDay = new TimeModel() {ID = 0, Day = DateTime.Now};
        var previousSaturday = currentDay.Day.AddDays(-(int)currentDay.Day.DayOfWeek - 1);
        var nextFriday = previousSaturday.AddDays(6);

        var currentWeek = list.Where(p => p.Day.DayOfYear >= previousSaturday.DayOfYear && p.Day.DayOfYear <= nextFriday.DayOfYear).OrderBy(p => p.Day.DayOfYear).ToList();
```